# Dynamic $row output from array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to achieve dynamic $row values from an array, and show them as output. It keeps showing nothing while the values are already there.

This is what I have so far, where:

`$row["lg_".$val.""];` should return:

```
$lg_it
```

'it' is the $val from the array.

```
foreach($arrMapCookieToLang as $key => $val) {
    $shrtKey = $row["lg_".$val.""];

    <input type="text" name="lg_$val" value="$shrtKey">
}
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: If that's all within PHP tags you would want to `echo "<input type='text' name='lg_$val' value='$shrtKey' />";`. HTML outside of PHP tags does not need to be `echo`ed, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should result in a syntax error. Try the following:

```
<?php
foreach($arrMapCookieToLang as $key => $val) {
    $shrtKey = $row['lg_'.$val];
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="lg_<?= $val ?>" value="<?= $shrtKey ?>">
    <?php
}
```

Comment: This solution assumes that php shorttags are enabled. You can't rely on that - especially not in shared hosting environments.

Comment: @Andreas short echo tags are a given since Php 5.4, and this solution stays very close to the OP's original code.

Comment: Modified it a little but this one showed me my mistake first. Thank for your help all!

Comment: Thanks @Progrock and Andreas and Mistery for their input as well on this one. You can go endless on variables with this.

Comment: @Progrock thanks for clarification. Was new to me, that short echo tags ignore the ini settings since 5.4

Answer (score 1):

You've missed to echo your input-field:

```
foreach($arrMapCookieToLang as $key => $val) { 
    $shrtKey = $row["lg_".$val.""]; 
    echo '<input type="text" name="lg_' . $val .'" value="' . $shrtKey . '">';
}
```

Further, if you don't use the array key in the `foreach`-loop, you can omit the `$key =>`-part and just write

```
foreach($arrMapCookieToLang as $val) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead, the
<input type="text" name="lg_$val" value="$shrtKey">
```

Maybe you should use the

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"lg_" . "$val\" value=\"$shrtKey\">";
```

Comment: If you concat the variables to the input attributes, why are you escaping the double quotes, instead of using single qoutes for the echo-expression? This is much better for code readability (see my solution above)

Comment: Yeah, agree your variant is more readable. But the variant is also make sense.